# Grabbing fields from object and returning it in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two linked objects

```
{scope: "T4251", data: Array(500)}
{scope: "T7910", data: Array(500)}
{scope: "T213910", data: Array(500)}
```

and the data object consists of 500 of these fields (scope is linked to below)

```
{@id: "eddnsf", dateTime: "2018-12-12T07:30:00Z", value: -0.045}
{@id: "sfdkjk", dateTime: "2018-12-12T04:30:00Z", value: -0.345}
{@id: "dfjewf", dateTime: "2018-11-12T02:00:00Z", value: -0.445}
{@id: "dfjewf", dateTime: "2018-10-12T04:40:00Z", value: -0.045}
{@id: "dfjewf", dateTime: "2018-10-12T06:00:00Z", value: -0.145}
{@id: "dfjewf", dateTime: "2018-10-12T02:00:00Z", value: -0.045}
```

How do I iterate this multi-object by first getting a unique "scope" object then grabbing the dateTime only once per date (must be unique) objects from the data array contained in the scope's array object?

I want the unique dateTime grabbed to be put into a single array

Array should result in:

```
[unique dateTime, unique dateTime, unique dateTime]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Not sure what your expected output is supposed to be, will the following produce what you are looking for? `yourData.reduce((result,item)=>result.concat(item.data),[]).reduce(
  (result,item)=>(result[item.dateTime] = result[item.dateTime] || [],result[item.dateTime].push(item),result),{}
)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with two functions.
First collects the dateTimes

```
const extractField= (data, field) => data.map( obj => obj[field])
```

Second filters the doubles

```
const filterDoubles = array => array.reduce( (result, item) => result.indexOf(item) > -1 ? result : result.concat(item),[])
```

Then :

```
filterDoubles(extractField(yourObject, 'dateTime'));
```

Comment: But the {@id} object is part of the scope object (array500)

Comment: Then, I'm not sure I fully understand what you need. Can you be more specific about it ?